# Undefined variable: sdsdsd in line 10 and 11

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Here is the code i am working on:

```
<?php
include('../connect.php');
$id=$_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'];
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM advisory WHERE     tid='$id'");
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($results))
{
    $sdsdsd=$rows['level'];
    $sdsd=$rows['section'];
}

echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$sdsdsd.'" name="level" />';
echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$sdsd.'" name="section" />';
echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$id.'"     name="tidsss" />';
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM prereg WHERE     level='$sdsdsd' AND  section='$sdsd'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo '<tr class="record">';
    echo '<td  style="border-left: 1px solid     #C1DAD7">'.$row['fname'].'   '.$row['mname'].' '.$row['lname'].'</td>';
    echo '<td><div align="left"><input     type="hidden" value="'.$row['idnumber'].'"  name="idnumber[]" /><input type="hidden"     value="'.$row['schoolyear'].'"  name="schooly[]" /><input type="text" name="grade[]" />    </div></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
?>
```

I can't understand why the `$sdsdsd` variable is undefined?

Comment: It means it not getting into the while loop. Make sure your query is fine. Try `die(mysql_error());` after your query. Also define your varialbe before loop `$sdsdsd= '';` Also you missing `session_start();`. **NOTE:** mysql_* function are now officially deprecated.

Comment: does the `SELECT` fetch any results?

Comment: May be $sdsdsd is not defined.

Comment: Your echo statements are outside the while loop, and $sdsdsd is inside

Comment: You're only echoing the values from the last row of the results. Why are you ignoring all the other rows? If there's only one row, why are you using a loop?

Comment: where is your `session_start();` statement in code?

Answer (score 1):

Probably because your request returns nothing.

So your while loop is never executed and your variables never defined.

You should initialize them before the loop.

```
<?php
// […]
$sdsdsd = null;
$sdsd = null;
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($results))
{
     $sdsdsd=$rows['level'];
     $sdsd=$rows['section'];
}
// […]
?>
```

**Note:** These are really bad names for variables by the way. Variables' name should explain briefly what they contain or what are their purpose, etc.

Comment: Bad names? What if they're the standard deviation of the standard deviation of the standard deviation? :-)

Comment: @jeromej thank you so much .. i finally figured it out. yeah i agree i changed the name of the variable as your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are setting those variables inside the `while` loop and using them outside, it's a safe bet you're therefore not actually entering the `while` loop at all.

You need to check the return value from `mysql_fetch_array` - if it's false, then you query is failing somehow. First thing I would do is output `$id` to see what is being used in the query.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `session_start();` at top and because of that this statement is failing

```
$id=$_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'];
```

since this statement is failing and `$id` becomes `NULL` and your query is not giving result.

Comment: It might be in the `connect.php`?

Comment: Could be, although that name sounds like it's for initializing the DB connection.

Comment: @JeromeJ might be , we are not sure. As per I see that is the real problem here.

Comment: @JeromeJ thank you guys i got now. i changed the the names of my variables then i just defined them silly me..,

Comment: @Yogesh Suthar thank you guys i got now. i changed the the names of my variables then i just defined them silly me..,

Answer (score 0):

Sure that there is a affected row? When there is no row, you don't set the variables `$sdsdsd` and `$sdsd`. Try a `var_dump` on `$rows` and other debugging!

Comment: Or simply make sure that PHP doesn't stupidly hide lots of errors when you could need them. For instance, you can put `error_reporting(-1);` at the beginning of your code and PHP will display all the errors.

Comment: Sure. That was meant by "other debugging". And when PHP doesn't give any errors add `ini_set("display_errors", "on");`, too or edit the config file of php.

Answer (score 0):

You should learn to declare the variable first and then use it, currently you are assigning variable $sdsdsd inside the while it is never available outside. Hence decalre it befor while loop

```
$sdsdsd = "";
$sdsd    = "";
```